# Accessing mysql data in oracle

Tags: mysql, oracle, oracle11g, data-warehouse

I import data from MySQL db to oracle 11g on a daily basis using a dblink.Data import is working fine(i use a insert as select ), but the imported varchar columns in oracle show something like this (empty spaces in between the letters) .

```
d o c M g r / w o r k f l o w / q b y u e d u
```

i use this for every column that gets inserted

```
select replace("field2",' ','') field2 from
```

Do we have any setting or any Unicode/Characterset with which I can insert without using replace function.

Comment: Are the character sets in Oracle and Mysql different? Try to CONVERT() the data on Mysql to the Oracle character set.

Answer (score 0):

Use the `REPLACE` function in your insert.

```
INSERT INTO yourtable
(field1, field2, field3)
SELECT field1, REPLACE("field2",' ',''), field3
FROM yourmysqltable;
```

Comment: I am already doing that,The number of table using this is increasing over a period of time. I am looking for a generic solution that can be applied across the schema.

Comment: adding HS_NLS_NCHAR=UCS2 to the initXXXX.ora file solved this issue.DBA made these changes and it works with a replace function.

Answer (score 0):

adding HS_NLS_NCHAR=UCS2 to the initXXXX.ora file solved this issue.DBA made these changes and it works with a replace function